# Not able to select photo from camera folder in android

Tags: android

One of my client is saying that he is not able to select photo from gallery (camera folder) but he is able to select photo from other folder.

My android app has following things

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
```

and

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 25
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it happens when `Bitmap` can't be loaded because the height and width of the image is larger in size which is `2048*2048`. Images captured through camera are usually large in size so, It is good practice to resize the image.

**Below is just an example to crop image if large in size,and does not take care of image ratio**

```
    public class InputImageCompressor extends Activity{

    public static void compressInputImage(Uri inputImageData, Context context, ImageView newIV)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        //Uri inputImageData = data.getData();
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmapInputImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), inputImageData);
            if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() > 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() > 2048)
            {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1024, 1280, true);
                newIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() > 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() < 2048)
            {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1920, 1200, true);
                newIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() < 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() > 2048)
            {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1024, 1280, true);
                newIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() < 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() < 2048)
            {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, bitmapInputImage.getWidth(), bitmapInputImage.getHeight(), true);
                newIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Use this in your `onActivityResult` as:

```
InputImageCompressor.compressInputImage(data, activity_context, imageView_to_place_image(imageview));
```

Comment: I tried to select image with 3840 * 2160 from gallary (download folder), Its working fine ....

Comment: Yep, but try to compress the image coming from camera it will work